# jQuery - Get element near string

Tags: html, jquery, string, jquery-selectors

I have a question. I had a string from HTML page. I need to capture element "near" a particular string, like this one:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
Ratings:
<strong><a href="http://www.foo.co">Kids +13</a></strong>
```

I need to get "Ratings:" and then capture the closest next element. Does I can do with jQuery? I had try it but I cannot understand which selector for text "Ratings:" I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not wrap the word `ratings` in a `span` with a class? It would make the selector infinitely easier. If not, you'll have to use `contents()` and then go digging around in `textNodes`, which will not be pretty.

Comment: As Rory McCrossan said it would be easier with a wrapped element, but you can start with a syntax like this `$('*:contains("Ratings:")');`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is give your  a class like this:

```
<a href="#" class="ratings">Kids +13</a>
```

In your jQuery it is then simply this:

```
$('.ratings').html()
```

This will return:
[image: Chrome Console output]

If you want to save it, simply add

```
var rating = $('.ratings').html()
```

If you have more then one rating, it will be a little more complicated, but not by much.

Comment: I cannot modify the source page, so the page is as is.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/LykFa/1/

```
 $("body:contains(Ratings\:)").find("strong").html();
```

It's not pretty, and won't work under all circumstances, but it does work for your example. If you can give other examples we may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your solution, but it returns a huge array of strong tags. Because I think it check if BODY contains "Ratings:", and if this is true, it search all "strong" tags. It is not good!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Ratings:` text in a `<span>` tag and apply a `class` attribute, like this:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
<span class="ratings">Ratings:</span>
<strong><a href="http://www.foo.co">Kids +13</a></strong>
```

Then you can select the `Ratings:` text, like this:

```
$(".ratings:contains(Ratings\:)")
```

Finally, you can use the jQuery `.next()` function to get the immediately following sibling (`<a>` tag in your case) of the selected element, like this:

```
$(".ratings:contains(Ratings\:)").next()
```

See example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrgfk/).